# Why when you vertically shake a pendulum very fast it goes upward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators

So I put a pendulum on a vibrating machine, I turned on the machine and the pendulum went up instead of down I thought it would go down because of friction(not only friction there others involved.) I'm very confused, so could you explain why it happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Kapitza's pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapitza%27s_pendulum). It is not surprising that the pendulum is all over the place when one pumps the system with an external force. The surprise is instead that the inverted position is a stable equilibrium for the [effective potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapitza%27s_pendulum#Equilibrium_positions) of the pendulum. For details, see the Wikipedia page.